# Maven build fails ONLY when run with jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, maven-3

I have a Java project that is committed to GitHub. The project consists of 3 modules. I have configured the Jenkins Workflow Multibranch Pipeline plugin to build the 3 modules.

```
node {
   // Mark the code checkout 'stage'....
  // stage 'Checkout'

   // Get some code from a GitHub repository
   git url: 'git@github.com:me/myproject.git', credentialsId: '###'

   // Get the maven tool.
   // ** NOTE: This 'M3' maven tool must be configured
   // **       in the global configuration.
   def mvnHome = tool 'M3'

   stage 'Build module 1'
   sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn -f module-1/ clean install"

   stage 'Build module 2'
   sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn -f module-2/ clean install"

   stage 'Build module 3'
   sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn -f module-3/ clean install"
}
```

Maven builds the first 2 modules with no problem. But on the third module I get the following error:

```
 Compilation failure
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/.../MyClass.java:[136,44] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setStore(java.util.UUID,java.util.UUID,java.util.Date,int)
  location: variable _storeService of type com.my.module3.interfaces.StoreService
```

I have red that there may be a problem with the version of `maven-compiler-plugin` so I updated it to the latest `3.5.1` version, but it did not help.

These are the maven plugins that I use in all 3 of the modules:

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName>module3-${project.version}</finalName>
                        <artifactSet>
                            <includes>
                                <include>*:*</include>
                            </includes>
                        </artifactSet>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <manifestEntries>
                                    <Main-Class>com.my.module3.App</Main-Class>
                                    <Implementation-Title>${project.name}</Implementation-Title>
                                    <Implementation-Version>${project.version}</Implementation-Version>
                                    <Implementation-Vendor-Id>${project.groupId}</Implementation-Vendor-Id>
                                    <Implementation-Vendor>${project.organization.name}</Implementation-Vendor>
                                </manifestEntries>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

When I build the module in IntelliJ there are no errors. I even pulled the repository in a new folder and used the `mvn clean install` command for the module3 and it finishes without a problem.

I have no idea where the problem is. It does not seem that there is something wrong with my code, as it works correctly (I have debugged it). Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems the storeservice is not the latest version. Because Jenkin needs to checkout the source code before building. You should check: latest source code of module 3 was committed to Git? If it was, you can go to Jenkins build folder and check if it got latest version of the module 3 source code. When you build on Intelli.., the source code was the latest. So the build was successful

Comment: The code is the latest version. I even deleted the `git` row, copied the code from my dev folder and pasted it in the Jenkins workspace folder. Also I checked the files. The code is there.

Comment: Try removing .m2 folder from your jenkins server. That way jenkins will trigger downloading of all your dependencies and you well get new version. Actually problem you have encountered is quite common.

Comment: @BrankoIlic Thank you. This fixed the problem. Can you write an answer, so that I can mark it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing .m2 folder from your jenkins server. That way jenkins will trigger downloading of all your dependencies and you well get new version. Actually problem you have encountered is quite common.

Comment: Just one more question. Do I have to delete the .m2 folder before every build? It seems quite redundant.

Comment: Nah. Just delete it once so you get new dependencies. 
Maven is kinda tricky if you, for example have snapshot versions you may end up with wrong version of your module if you are not careful. Also, as @João Marcos has already mentioned i too keep Delete Workspace before build starts option checked. First you need to install  "Workspace Cleanup Plugin" under "manage jenkins -> manage plugins"

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about the plugin. The problem is that I use the Workflow Multibranch Pipeline plugin and it seems that there is no Delete Workspace option for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the option "Delete Workspace before build starts" in Build Environment configuration.

This option is accessible after install "Workspace Cleanup Plugin"

Comment: Where is the location of this setting? I have enabled the "Discard old items" setting, but I can't find the one that you are talking about.

Comment: Open the build configuration, make CTRL+F and find it. This is inside "Build Environment" options

Comment: Possibli after installing this: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Workspace+Cleanup+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after moving jenkins folder to another drive. Confusingly, running maven manually from a cmd in the remote server worked fine, but failed when running from pipeline. Deleting .m2 didn't help. The cause was that before moving I did `jenkins.exe uninstall` and then `jenkins.exe install` to update windows service / jenkins home variable (I found this as a recommendation somewhere). The new service had configured to use system user, and so confusingly used .m2 located somewhere inside the C:/Windows directory. Going to services, and changing in properties dialog the user the service to run as solved it. Somewhat offtopic to OP, but I figure this may prove useful to others, since this question was the first promising thing I found when searching for my issue